# How to make an Imageview overlap the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I'm stacking ImageView's on eachother from bottom to top (by layout_above), but what I want to make the top one overflow/overlaps the screen. Normally this would resize/crop the imageview to make it fit in the screen, but I want to to be like in the picture shown below.

How would I be able to achieve this?

[image: Trying to Achieve]

Comment: Do you intend for this to be the full functionality or do you intend to be able to add more and scroll through many, like a scroll view.  Or just have it slightly outside of the view.

Comment: @AshleyAlvarado just have it slightly outside of the view, remaining the size which it would be when it was inside the screen view. ( it resizes now to make it fit within the bounds of the screen size)